# Darkmode activated by device

Tags: feature-request, design, dark-mode

At the moment Dark mode is activated by profile, not by device.

I know we can enable it in our profile, but that's not the point here.

I would like to access Dark mode **only** when accessing the site using Android. While using Desktop version I'm comfortable with using the white screen, and it confuses me to use Darkmode there.

Doing it would help me and more users with the same problem and stop wasting time going forth and back to edit the mode (I ended up just using the white mode).

Comment: You can set your preference (which is by profile) to use "System setting" (which will use your system's settings). For instance, I have it set to use "System setting". My Windows 10 desktop is set to use Dark Mode, so I see Stack Overflow in dark mode. My Android device is set to use Light Mode, so I see Stack Overflow in light mode. If I change my Android device to use Dark Mode, I see Stack Overflow in dark mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your preference (which is by profile) to use "System setting" (which will use your system's settings).

[image: Theme setting (in dark mode)]

For instance, I have it set to use "System setting". My Windows 10 desktop is set to use Dark Mode, so I see Stack Overflow in dark mode.

My Android device is set to use Light Mode, so I see Stack Overflow in light mode.

[image: Android, showing light mode]

If I change my Android device to use Dark Mode, I see Stack Overflow in dark mode.

[image: Android, showing dark mode]

Of course, I am using the "full site" link at the bottom.

Comment: Then when you go to your Desktop, do you have it in Dark-mode ? (considering you changed on Android)

Comment: I didn't change my Stack Overflow preference (you can see it's the same in all three screenshots). I changed my Android settings (Settings > Display > Dark theme (Off). It's in Dark mode, but only because my Windows 10 settings are set to dark mode.

Comment: Ah got it, clever! Going to Settings > Theme > Dark in Chrome really does it, thank you

Comment: Dark Mode is also enabled using battery saver.

Comment: Currently this stopped working on my device, unsure why.